# MSSQL: Conditional noexpand hint for view that may be indexed or not

Tags: sql-server, optimization, materialized-view

As documented in other Q&A on this site, if you create an indexed view you may have to give the `noexpand` hint to use it as such.  Without the hint, cheaper versions of MSSQL will always treat it as an ordinary view, and even the 'enterprise' versions may still need the hint in practice.

But `noexpand` is not valid on an ordinary, not-indexed view.  That means if you change a view from indexed to ordinary, queries stop working.  You can't fully hide the implementation detail of whether it's an indexed view or not, unless you make another wrapper view.

Is there some hint that means the same thing as `noexpand` when applied to an indexed view, but is a no-op when applied to an ordinary view?

`select name from myview (noexpand_if_necessary) where id = 55`

Then if `myview` is an indexed view you get the benefit of the indexes; if `myview` happens to be an ordinary view the query happens as if the hint were not given.

I'm currently using MSSQL 2008 R2 but I would be interested in answers for newer MSSQL versions too.